# Anyone can give me some details about Active contour model. I need details, How can use it, about energetic equation and their cods?

Tags: model, contour

I need to learn Active contour Model.

I want to know their detail including Energetic equation. How can use it and their cods I need.

Any research paper, Website, Your notes and your knowledge are accepted.  I need to know how work active contour model.